# Отключение сортировки по весам в layout.PieChart Яндекс.Карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как можно отключить сортировку по весам в layout.PieChart?

Я попробовал присвоить `properties.data` данные в нужной мне последовательности, но слайсы всё равно отображаются от большего веса в меньшему.

Пробовал так (`manager` — экземпляр ObjectManager):

```
manager.clusters.events.add('add', function(event) {
    var target = event.get('child');
    target.properties.data = [
        { weight: 1, color: 'red' },
        { weight: 2, color: 'green' },
        { weight: 3, color: 'blue' },
    ];
});
```

Ожидая увидеть начиная сверху **красный**, **зелёный**, **синий**, получаю **синий**, **зелёный**, **красный**, что совсем не радует.

Comment: Как выяснилось после просмотра исходников — никак, только делать свой layout с нужным функционалом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку сортировка автоматическая и не опциональная в API, могу, как некий костыль, предложить разбивать все элементы на нужное количество единичных элементов нужного цвета с нулевой границей:

```
manager.clusters.events.add('add', function(event) {
    var target = event.get('child');
    target.properties.data = [
        {weight: 1, color: 'red'},
        {weight: 1, color: 'green'},
        {weight: 1, color: 'green'},
        {weight: 1, color: 'blue'},
        {weight: 1, color: 'blue'},
        {weight: 1, color: 'blue'}
    ];
});
```

Так диаграмма должна отображать элементы в порядке добавления.

Comment: Я рассматривал этот вариант, но 1) без обводок в моём случае выглядит это не айс; 2) будет работать только если Array.prototype.sort() стабильна (что по-моему не является обязательным требованием к ней). В результате для своих целей я стал делать собственную круговую диаграмму на основе PieChart, но потом потребность в собственной сортировке отпала. Однако, отмечу ответ, т.к. в некоторых случаях он может быть полезен.

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение - переписать прототип Array.sort:

```js
const originalSort = Array.prototype.sort;
Array.prototype.sort = function(...arguments) {
  if(this[0]?.weight && this[0]?.color)
        return this;
    return originalSort.call(this, ...arguments);
};
```

Если необходимо выборочно отключать сортировку, то при формировании data для pieChart можно добавить уникальный элемент и проверять его наличие:

```js
    const originalSort = Array.prototype.sort;
    Array.prototype.sort = function(...arguments) {
      if(this[0]?.pieChartNoSort)
            return this;
        return originalSort.call(this, ...arguments);
    };

    //Data for pieChart
    var data=[
      {weight:1, color:'green',pieChartNoSort:1},
      {weight:1, color:'red'},
    ];
```